# How do I allow access to a method in MVC?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make an AJAX call to a model that I have in my MVC project. I keep receiving the following error:

> POST foobar/GetDate 405 (Method Not Allowed)

(Where 'foobar' is my localhost:port format for the MVC project.)

I haven't played around with routing in the project yet, as I'm not sure what a route to a script should look like. I know how to properly route views at this point. Here are some code snippets:

In my MVC Project, I have a Model with the following method:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDate()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

In my Index.aspx file, I have this code:

```
<button class="getDate">Get Date!</button>
<div class="dateContainer">Empty</div>
```

And in my script.js file, I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "GetDate",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        // Replace text in dateContainer with string from GetDate method
        $(".dateContainer").text(msg.d);
    },
    complete: function (jqHXR, textStatus) {
        // Replace text in dateContainer with textStatus
        if (textStatus != 'success') {
            $(".dateContainer").text(textStatus);
        }
    },
});
```

My end goal is to send XML data to my method in the C# model, then parse and save the XML document.

Right now, I'll settle on trying to link up the AJAX request in jQuery to the C# method I have. I'm positive it has something to do with routing and syntax.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `GetDate` should be a controller method annotated with with the `HttpPost` attribute that returns `Json(DateTime.Now)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you have an `[WebMethod]` method in an MVC Project ?

In MVC, you can have `action` methods in your `controller`s. You can call this from ajax as well

```
public class WebController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetDate()
    {
       return Content(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

You can call it from your javascript like this (with jQuery)

```
$.get("@url.Action("GetDate","Web")",function(result){
     alert("The result from ajax call is "+result);
});
```

If you are doing a `POST` call to the method, make sure to decorate your action method with POST attribute.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveUser(string userName)
    {
       //do something and return something
    }
```

You can even return **JSON** from your action method to your ajax call's callback function. There is a `JSON` method in `Controller` (the base class of our WebController) class to do this.

```
    public ActionResult GetMagician(string userName)
    {
       return Json(new { Name="Jon", Job="Stackoverflow Answering" },
                                  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: You forgot about [HttpPost] attribute

Comment: @bobek: The example was using a GET method. Anyway i updated answer to include details about how to handle POST

Comment: @Shyju - the post actually used a POST ajax request.

Comment: @MystereMan: Yea. I meant the example in my answer. Anyway, i updated with POST details